# What's the other gender of 'drone'?

Tags: word-request, word-usage

My daughter is in Grade 4 and there's a 'fill in the blank' in her worksheet.

> Example: The opposite gender of a lion is called ***lioness.***

Now the question...

> The opposite gender of a drone is called **___________**.

This forced me to look up on the Internet and strange, I did not get it!

Comment: I don't get it either.  *Drone* isn't a gender.  But they're male, and *workers* and *queens* are female.

Comment: @snailplane that's how they ask. How do you ask it? The opposite of *what* is *bitch?* can be questioned as What's the opposite gender of a dog?

Comment: __Can we have more context?__ Female wasps are usually _workers_, as are female ants, except the fertile queens. _Drones_ are fertile ants and wasps.

Comment: More context? How? Question edited (though) for clarity.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's General Knowledge that female social insects (in species where the males are all *drones*) may be either *queens* or *workers*. There is no single term for that category.

Comment: ...but please note that by the time I closevoted, the best available "answer" (and the details of why the *teacher's* question is flawed) had been posted (both as Answers and Comments). I would not dismiss *your* question without ensuring you'd been given a reasonable response - but since you're only asking because of a misinformed *teacher*, I don't think the ELL question as posed here needs to be kept open.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You mean the problem is just the *very first line?* This question without that line would have gone smoothly? What mistake did I make mentioning that? Why the **focus** is on *who gave the sheet* than the gist -*What's the other gender of a drone is called?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers and it's human tendency, one (you especially with such high reputation) *initiates* close-voting, others are sure to follow - the problem I see in most of my 'closed' questions. Anyway, hope I find this answer elsewhere on the Internet. But frankly, a *trust* factor gets affected.

Comment: I'm not with you. The question is based on a false assumption by your daughter's teacher. I can't know whether the teacher expects the answer *worker* or *queen*, but that's really beside the point - through inexcusable ignorance, that teacher posed an "unanswerable" question. Through perfectly excusable ignorance, you've repeated the question here, and all relevant information has been given to you. What more would you hope for if the question were left open (or *reopened*)? What relevance does that teacher's error have to others wanting to learn English?

Answer (score 1):

Well, with all the confusion about the wording aside (there are honestly better ways to formulate the textbook question...), it seems clear by now that what is meant is:

A **drone** is a male ant, bee or wasp. The female of that is **worker**, so *that* is what the textbook wants as an answer, I guess.

That looking on the 'net is confusing may have to do with the fact that you will find a lot more articles about unmanned aircraft than about male insects nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

[Drone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drone) is a male bee, wasp or ant. So opposite gender would be female.

Answer (score -2):

Harem is female workers in the queen's abode. Drones are sterile male worker bees; whereas harem are female workers occasionally bearing out-of-wedding children of kings and emperors.

Comment: This is incorrect. In a hive, drones are fertile males that do not work. Non-queen female bees are workers.